# master details controll not display content in new page

Tags: android, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I am trying master detail navigation by clicking button to view detail from the given data

page1.html

```
<a class="button icon button-block button-calm icon-right ion-android-arrow-dropright-circle" ng-class="{'button-balanced': file.status == 'open', 'button-assertive': file.status == 'closed'}" href="#filedetails" ng-repeat="file in file | orderBy:'-status'" ng-click="onSelectFile(n)" >File Ref No:{{file.num}}<br>
        Description:{{file.descript}}<br>
        Status:{{file.status}}</a><br>
```

page2.html

```
<div class="col">: {{file.num}}</div>
      <div class="col">: {{file.casedet}}</div>
```

controllerpage

```
.controller('caseFileCtrl', function($scope,$http,$location) {
     $scope.file=[
        {num:"1",descript:"consumer",status:"closed",casedet:"cleared"},
        {num:"2",descript:"literal",status:"open", casedet:"process"},
        {num:"3",descript:"literal",status:"closed", casedet:"cleared"},
        {num:"4",descript:"consumer",status:"open",casedet:"proess"}
                 ];
$scope.onSelectFile = function(n)
{
    $location.url('/casefile/'+ n.num);
}



 })

  .controller('fileDetailsCtrl', function($scope,$stateParams) {
    $scope.file={num:$stateParams.num, casedet:'file'+$stateParams.casedet};

  })
```

am not able to view num and casedet in other page

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a service to share data between controllers.

`js/services.js`

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('File', function($log) {
    this.files = [];
    return {
        /**
         * Get the list of files.
         * @returns Returns the list of files.
         */
        get: function(){
            return this.files;
        },
        /**
         * Set the list of files.
         * @param files The files to set.
         */
        set: function(files){
            this.files = files;
        }
    };
});
```

Include in your `index.html`:

```
<!-- Your scripts -->
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
```

Include in your `app.js` dependencies:

```
angular.module('yourModuleName', [/* Your dependencies */, 'starter.services'])
```

Config section of your `app.js`

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })

    .state('app.caseFileCtrl', {
      url: '/casefile',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/files.html',
          controller: 'caseFileCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

  .state('app.single', {
    url: '/casefile/:fileId',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/file.html',
        controller: 'fileDetailsCtrl'
      }
    }
  });
  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/casefile');
});
```

Use your `File` service in `js/controllers.js`

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('caseFileCtrl', function($scope, File, $state) {
  $scope.files = [
    {num:"1",descript:"consumer",status:"closed",casedet:"cleared"},
    {num:"2",descript:"literal",status:"open", casedet:"process"},
    {num:"3",descript:"literal",status:"closed", casedet:"cleared"},
    {num:"4",descript:"consumer",status:"open",casedet:"proess"}
  ];

  File.set($scope.files);

  $scope.onSelectFile = function(n){
    console.log("Go to:", '/casefile/'+ n);
    $state.go("app.single", {fileId: n});
  };

})

.controller('fileDetailsCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $filter, File) {
    console.log("fileId:", $stateParams.fileId);
    $scope.file = $filter('filter')(File.get(), {num: $stateParams.fileId})[0];
});
```

You can see a working solution on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gl15Yc1BhcqFI7GFjGmp).

Some additional points:

- avoid to use `ng-repeat="file in file"`. I would prefer something like: `ng-repeat="file in files"`
- it's better to redirect to another route using `$state.go` and not `$location`;
- if you're using `ng-click` directive on an `a` tag and you use it to redirect to another view, it's better to not include `href="#filedetails"` attribute to avoid double redirect;
- `a` it's ok for a list of elements but also take a look to [`ion-list`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionList/).